# Install dpkg-depcheck in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, dpkg, repository, official-repositories

I'm attempting to compile a deb package using 12.04 but am unable to run a dpkg-depcheck on ubuntu 12.04.  The command doesn't exist on the server I'm using and isn't a package in the repositories either.  (It is, however, on my desktop machine)  How might I install it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

devscripts are scripts to make the life of a Debian Package maintainer easier.

dpkg-depcheck, dpkg-genbuilddeps: determine the packages used during the build of a Debian package; useful for determining the Build-Depends control field needed. dependencies/recommendations for the dpkg-depcheck script are: *build-essential, strace*.

Comment: Hah! Thanks for the response! I just found it right as you posted the answer. :-P  I'll check off the answer as soon as they let me.  Thanks again!